# How do frameworks like Spock or Mockito work?

Tags: junit, mockito, spock

What is the mechanism that frameworks like Spock or Mockito work.
You can mock a method call . You can mock a whole class.
But how is that possible ??
It means you must be able to manipulate the normal execution of code.

Comment: No, they just e.g. create anonymous subclasses of the target class and use reflection to delegate method calls. They are open source, you can just look at what they are doing.

Comment: But how they interrupt the normal code execution. Where is code to see that ?

Comment: Why would you think they "interrupt" anything? Maybe show a snippet of code where you are confused what is happening.

Comment: e.g. in spock you could do object.anotherobject.someString() >> "hello world"   . So if this method somewhere in code gets called it will return hello world  and it will never go to the real method

Comment: Open questions do not belong on Stack Overflow. Hence, I voted to close it. Please do not get me wrong, the question is interesting and I could write dozens of pages about it. Basically, you want to familiarise yourself with the concept of dynamic proxies. They come in different flavours, depending on whether you want to intercept (and maybe mock/stub) interface methods or class methods. The simplest case is the former and can be implemented with [JDK proxies](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies). For the latter, you can use e.g. CGLIB or Byte Buddy.